# Safely Hooking a Switch up to an OEM Power Supply?

Tags: prusa-i3-rework, switching-power-supply, wiring, wire-type

I ordered an [OEM Power Supply](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007KG0ZYI) and I intend to hook up with [this rocker switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00511QVVK) I believe it's like the one specified in the [Power Supply Documentation](http://reprap.org/wiki/Power_Supply#OEM_type_PSU) which reads:

> In the US, IEC320 C14 plug connections are common, but use your
>   preferred standard.

I've also seen where this was attached in [this thingiverse project](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:31659).

Inside the switch I've also added an F4AL250V fuse.

Now what's confusing me is, that the [this rocker switch](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00511QVVK) on the back reads 10A 250V~ so I'm wondering if it's safe to use.

The switch will be connected to the house mains via a plug and wired just like in the [this thingiverse project](http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:31659), so it can be the input into my [OEM Power Supply](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007KG0ZYI) via the black (hot - L), white (Common - N) and Green (Ground) wires.

For the connecting wires I stripped a black PC Tower wire to get at the black, white, and ground wires inside it.

http://reprap.org/wiki/Power_Supply#OEM_type_PSU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 250V a rating for 10A means 2500 Watts, which is fairly enough to use with a typical 3D printer. Make sure that the wire you use to connect the switch to the power supply can also take the current you need. Easiest way to get a cable that is safe to use is salvaging a mains cable from other devices. I would not use wires that were made for low power use and with unsolid connections.

*edit: I'm still not sure which cable you intended to use from this tower PC. If it is a mains cable like this 
https://www.google.com/search?q=mains+power+cable&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL6Y23l9zLAhUCrRoKHXvsArsQ_AUIBygB&biw=1421&bih=922
you should be on the safe side.

Answer (score 2):

The power supply that you posted is 12v 360w.  This means that (in the USA with 120v power), it will draw 3 amps at 120v.  Your switch is rated for 10A at 250V so it works.

The switch should be placed to interrupt the HOT wire coming from the wall to your power supply.

If you happen to be using 240v power, it is also safe as you would be drawing 1.5 amps at 240v which is still within the spec of the switch.